# how do i make win algorithm or a tic tac toe game

Tags: javascript, dom, logic

i am creating a tic tac toe game to help me practice module pattern but i am pretty stuck.

i have a board array and a winning combination array because the initial walkthrough asked me to make those  but i am not sure what to do with them.

the board array is supposed to hold the x's and o's but i have instead directly injected the field elements with the x's and o's. i need the message to change when the combination sets and also a way to restart the game.

```js
//player factory function
const createPlayer = (name,marker) => {
    return {name,marker}
}

//gameboard object
const gameBoard = (() => {
   //create board array
    let board = []
    for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
        board.push("")
    }

   

    //add event listeners on each field that will mark field and change player's turn state
    const fields = document.querySelectorAll(".field") 
    const nextTurn = document.querySelector(".message")

   
    let turn = 0
    
    fields.forEach((field) => {
        field.addEventListener('click',handleClick,{once:true})

        function handleClick() {
            
                if(turn %= 2) {
                    field.innerHTML = "O"
                    field.classList.toggle("marker")
                    nextTurn.innerHTML= "Player X's turn"}
                    
                    else {
                    field.innerHTML = "X"
                    field.classList.toggle("marker")
                    nextTurn.innerHTML= "Player O's turn"}
                    
                    turn ++
    

        }
        
    })

    //restart game
    const restart = document.getElementById("restart-button")

    restart.addEventListener("click",clicke)

    function clicke() {
        const fields = document.querySelectorAll(".field").innerHTML=""
    }
        

    return {
        board, 
    }
})()

// game object
const game = (() => {

    //declare players
    const playerOne = createPlayer("player x", "x")
    const playerTwo = createPlayer("player o", "o")

    //starting point
    let activePlayer = playerOne
    let winnerDeclared = false
    let remainingSpots = 9

    //selectors
    let playerName = document.querySelector('.message') //alert next turn

    //winning conditons
    const winningConditons = [
        [0,1,2]
        [3,4,5]
        [6,7,8]
        [0,3,8]
        [1,4,7]
        [2,5,8]
        [0,4,8]
        [2,4,6]
    ];

    //check for winner
    function checkWinner() {

    }

    function declareTie(){
        playerName.innerHTML = "Its a tie!"
    }

    
}
)()
```

```css
:root{
    --blue1: #546482;
    --blue2: #312d44ca;
    --yellow1: #EBEC9A;
    --eggshell: #c5c3c6;
    --header: #bbf0fb;
    --font: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}



body{
    display: grid;
    font-family: var(--font);

}

.container{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.header{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 20vh;
    background-color: var(--blue1);
    border-bottom: 3px solid var(--blue2);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.body-container{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 80vh;
    background-color: var(--eggshell);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:space-around;
    align-items: center;

}



.message{
    font-size: 50px;
    color: var(--blue2);
}

#restart-button{
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: 1000;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    background-color: var(--blue1);
    color: var(--header);
    border: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    min-width: 130px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#restart-button:hover{
    background-color: #4a5466;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

.gameboard{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
.field{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color:  #ededee;
    
}

.field:hover{
    background-color:  rgb(248,248,255);
}

.marker{
    color: var(--blue2);
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;


}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header-text">
                Tic-Tac-Toe
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="body-container">
            <div class="message">Player X's turn</div>
            <div class="gameboard">
                <div class="field"></div>
                <div class="field"></div>
                <div class="field"></div>
                <div class="field"></div>
                <div class="field"></div>
                <div class="field"></div>
                <div class="field"></div>
                <div class="field"></div>
                <div class="field"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="center">
                <button id="restart-button">Restart</button>
            </div>
   
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: To be honest you're asking a lot of questions at the same time! 1 - You need a way to check all the field contents to see if somebody won. 2 - You need a way to compare the X,O contents with your win states. 3 - You need a way to reset the game. Maybe you can make your question simpler by starting with 1 problem?

Comment: you're right. how do i compare the x,o contents with my win states that i have set in the array?

Comment: You can read the contents of a field using your own `fields` variable. For example `let state = [];` and then `state[0] = fields[0].innerHTML`. This will give you a `X` or a `O` in the state array. Getting all values of all fields is your first step! I recommend getting that working first, before you start on the next problem.